# Django Model with non-unique names

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a simple kanban style board for my task manager app in Django 3.0.3. I've already written the code for projects and tasks, but I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to create the models for the kanban boards. I currently have two models, but can I do this in one for simplicity?

My basic requirement is that every project can have its own board, and each board will have multiple panels. Here is an example:

Board: Development

1. Backlog
2. Started
3. Development
4. etc...

Board: Operations

1. Requested
2. Working
3. Pending
4. etc...

With only one model, I'm not sure if this will have the flexibility I need to fully design it. But having multiple models may be too cumbersome to manage for the ultimate user. Here are my current models:

```
class Board(models.Model):
    """
    Defines Kanban boards
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="")
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        board_name = self.project.name + ":" + self.name
        return board_name


class BoardPanel(models.Model):
    """
    Defines panels in project board
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="")
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task)

    def __str__(self):
        panel_name = self.board.name + ":" + self.title
        return panel_name
```

Comment: Theoretically you can, but it's not a good approach for any use case. What you've done here is actually the better practice.

Comment: Confirming Mehran's statement. 2 models is far from being cumbersome, and it would be more clumsy to deal with consistency and integrity of your data if you stored in say a JSONField, or even a CharField.

Comment: Thanks @Mehran. The user asked me to make it easier to navigate in the Django Admin and reduce the number of DB tables. But it just made more sense to have 2 models in my mind. Can you move your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @JustinBoucher sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you can, but it's not a good approach for any use case. What you've done here is actually the better practice.

Also. in your comment you mention to make it easier to navigate. You can use Django Admin Inlines for that.

Something like this.

```
class BoardPanelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BoardPanel
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Board)
class BoardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'id', 'project',)
    inlines = [BoardPanelInline, ]
```

Comment: I have already added the inline. I also made a BoardTemplate model so they can select from a list of named templates. I'll just create a util script to auto-populate the board panels. Hopefully, that will be simple enough for them.